# Android Studio Setup Wizard Stuck on Downloading Components

Tags: android-studio

So far, I've run into a brick wall when trying to open Android Studio. Installation seems to run fine, but when I open the program for the first time, I am greeted with the setup wizard which informs me that it will be downloading components.

The first line in the dialog box tells me that the sdk has been installed in a specific location, which it then lists.

At the bottom, there are greyed-out navigation buttons for 'Back' 'Next' and 'Finish'. The 'Cancel' button is active, but when I click it, nothing happens.

There is no button for 'Show Details' to reveal what is going on behind the scenes.

Basically, this screen does not advance. I have tried on multiple different internet connections. I am not using a proxy.

When I hit cancel, the button becomes greyed-out, and nothing happens. The only way to exit the screen is to force close it in Task Manager.

I have tried running as an administrator.

I am currently running Windows 8.1.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Please checkout what's in the `C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio\system\log` I've seen this issue before and there were exceptions in that file because of network proxy issues or some other issues with downloading Android platform tools. I fixed this issue once by downloading the required build/platform tools manually with the Android SDK Manager after configuring some proxy settings in "Tools" > "Options"

Comment: Here is my log file

http://pastebin.com/6dmu1RpW

Comment: I have the build tools and the sdk already installed, so I'm not too sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for now was to use an older stable version. 1.0.2 worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the latest components manually.

1. Go to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
2. Open SDK Manager.exe
3. Update the packages.
4. Start Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Android Studio and clean all the junk files, then reinstall it should fix that!

First, Run "Control Panel" ⇒ "Programs and Features" ⇒ Uninstall "Android Studio"

Then make sure to delete any of these files if exist:

- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (this directory contains the SDK).

  C:\Users\username\.android

  C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudioX.X

  C:\Users\username\.gradle

  C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects (these are the Android projects written by you)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the folder /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk and it worked.