# Android Studio stuck on "Downloading Components"

Tags: android, windows, windows-8.1, android-studio-3.0

I'm already to install android studio ,and when i want to download components like **`sdk`** manager etc, I'm stuck in here

like this:

[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5JB2.png]]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885034/android-studio-setup-wizard-stuck-on-downloading-components

Comment: Same here... Tried it with 2 different computers, and with both of them the installation is stuck just as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue I became frustrated after seeing these downloads repeatedly which is not descriptive. Also it took lot of time to download on high speed internet.

Just wait it will be finished.

Comment: yeah i will be wait for it

Answer (score 0):

i had the same situation and i thought it was a problem but it's not. just wait until it finished . 
it needs hours to downmoad all components !