# Unable to download sdk components

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Whenever I try to start android studio, I get this:
[image]

What should I do?
It doesn't download and just keeps repeating this!

Comment: Does your firewall block it from accessing the site?

Comment: I don't think so
My firewall is turned off

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157989/android-studio-stuck-on-downloading-components

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298638/android-studio-first-run-stuck-at-downloading-components-window)
You can try the solution to avoid Downloading Components at startup so that AS launches and later on proceed manually.

> To disable "Downloading Components" at startup,
>
> Go to the installation directory of Android Studio. There you will
>   find a folder named "bin". Inside this folder there is a file named
>   "idea.properties". Open this file and add the following line to the
>   end of the file:
>
> disable.android.first.run=true What this will do is disable the check
>   that Android Studio performs on first run and decides to download all
>   that stuff.
>
> If it asks to save the file at some different place instead of
>   overwriting the original one, please check the access permissions to
>   the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and it was actually working fine, despite looking broken. Wait and see if the filename changes after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is some bug, but it's just process of downloading.

Just wait for end of downloading and all will be ok.