# Android Studio SDK download hanging

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I bought a new laptop for android development and was able to download Android Studio with no issues, but when it starts to download the SDK components it just won't start with the download, in fact, it brings the whole network down in my house.

I have made sure to run it as admin and also to add android studio to the windows firewall, also I disabled the antivirus just to make sure it was not being blocked.

Also, if I manually try to download those links it works, but that is not an ideal solution with how many components it downloads and also that I would need to update every now and then.

The image below shows how it just tries and tries with the same link not able to even begin the download.

I have search around but have not seen anyone with the same issue as me, what could it be? I have been able to download any other program and tool I wanted on this pc. It is an Acer Predator Helios 300, if that is of any help.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0RiV.png

Comment: Try using proxy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by looking at the logs as described here
**Please checkout what's in the C:\Users\username.AndroidStudio\system\log**
**Source** [Android Studio Setup Wizard Stuck on Downloading Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885034/android-studio-setup-wizard-stuck-on-downloading-components)

I found this warning 
2017-12-10 17:00:30,327 [d thread 2]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File C:\Users\est_c.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

Which led me to this post
[repositories.cfg could not be loaded in window 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028626/repositories-cfg-could-not-be-loaded-in-window-10)

**That had this solution: Error resolved by creating an empty repositories.cfg file.**

After doing that the download kick off. :D